# How to add an element to a 3d array?

Tags: r

I am trying to add elements into a multidimensional array, that I don't know the length of when it is declared, but it is not behaving as i would expect. I have seen that arrays in r are not static, and I have tried a bunch of different approaches, so I'm starting to go a little mad.

i have the array:

```r
diffAr <- array(0,dim = c(1,2))
```

that i set as part of a loop:

```r
diffAr[t,] <- c(cordX,cordY)
```

which works fine

```r
> diffAr
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
```

and the 1st go round this works fine, but on the second I get this error:

> Error in '[<-'('*tmp*', 2, , value = c(3, 5)) : subscript out of bounds

if arrays in r are dynamic, shouldn't this work, and just add another element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add rows to an array you can use rbind() and if you want to add columns you can use cbind(). In this case adding a second row with values 3 and 5 can be done like this (this will also work in your loop) :

```
diffAr <- array(0,dim = c(1,2))
diffAr[1,] <- c(2,1)

diffAr <- rbind(diffAr, c(3,5))
diffAr


> diffAr
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    5
```

Comment: Wow, cant believe i didn't check this one. Didn't think rbind worked with arrays for some reason... thanks though this has solved it!

Answer (score -1):

It's since you only have one row in your array.
here is what you set up:

```
diffAr <- array(0,dim = c(1,2))
```

which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

then, let's say you want to change it (in a loop or otherwise):

```
cordX <- 2
cordY <- 1
diffAr[1,] <- c(cordX,cordY)
```

now it looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
```

but if you (or your loop) asked for this (which is asking to put the new values in the second row, which doesn't exist):

```
diffAr[2,] <- c(cordX,cordY)
```

then you get the error since that row doesn't exist:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 2, , value = c(2, 1)) : subscript out of bounds
```

but you could keep changing the first row if you wanted:

```
diffAr[1,] <- c(3,5)
```

which works...

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
```

Comment: I am aware of this thanks, this is in a loop, and is needed to output to another function. When the array is declared i dont know how many times it will loop, so i need to be able to add elements, not use the ones i have already declared. Thanks for your answer though.